# How should I understand "turn" in this context?

Tags: meaning

The following line is from a song, so I suppose it could have omissions or use non-standard English:

> A man can be *turned* by a pretty face.

I'm not entirely sure the word used is actually "turned", but various lyrics websites seem to confirm it.

So, what exactly does this refer to? Physically turning around? Changing in a specific way? Attracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the context it could mean a lot of things. In fact many song writers *intentionally* make their lyrics mean multiple things. For example it could mean:

> 1- Turning The Head
>
> 2- Getting emotionally moved
>
> 3- Getting Attracted
>
> 4- Turning over a new leaf (i.e Reforming)
>
> 5- Switch Sides (i.e Become A Traitor)

Personally I think in this context it means getting emotionally moved, but it could mean any or all of the above.

Comment: Also 'switch sides', that is, become a traitor.

Comment: Could also be "turned on" (as in aroused).

Comment: @onomato: true butbnot on the context of the given example. You need the 'on' to invoke that meaning.

Comment: Personally, I think *turn* is enough to imply arousal when the context is what seeing a pretty woman can do to a man: http://www.lyricsfreak.com/n/nazareth/girls_20098599.html (And as this answer notes, the multiple possible meanings are intentional.)

Comment: @onomatomaniak I agree that it could be a possible meaning, but wouldn't it come under "Getting emotionally moved" or "Getting Attracted" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to the song [Girls](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/n/nazareth/girls_20098599.html). If you read it in context, it is not particularly specific, but the meaning is clear -- a pretty face can make a man act in a way that he would not do otherwise, the influence of a "girl" can make him go against his better judgement.

Comment: That's the one, yes. I guess the one downvote means that someone disagrees with you on this.